# Where does a gap in the waterfall view of chrome come from?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I reload a website with Ctrl+Shift+F5 in Chrome and on around every secound request, it takes very long to build.

I try to debug using the network tab and there is just a huge gap in the waterfall view.

What is chrome doing during that time? How can it be debugged further?

[image]

*edit* profiling view ... it's all "other"

[image]

[image]

*edit2*

Switchting it off and on again (reboot) solved the problem for now -> the question is still, what this kind of behavior means in the network tab.

Comment: Try using Performance panel in devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm I made an edit

Comment: It *probably* means something was eating up your network resources. Unfortunately, without a reproducible scenario there isn't much that can be done to figure out why.